# Optional seconds when serializing NodaTime.LocalTime?

Tags: c#, serialization, iso8601, nodatime, localtime

Is it possible to make a pattern for NodaTime's LocalTime, which matches the [ISO 8601 standard for times](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Times)? That is, can you make (minutes and) seconds optional, like you can make fractional seconds optional? I wish to be able to always have hours and minutes, but add everything else only when needed.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't exist in NodaTime currently, nor does it exist as [an option](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) for the built in `DateTime` and `DateTimeOffset` objects.

Probably the best you could do is to create two patterns and add some logic for which to use.

```
var p1 = LocalTimePattern.ExtendedIsoPattern;
var p2 = LocalTimePattern.CreateWithInvariantCulture("HH:mm");

// formatting
LocalTime t = // your input
var p = t.Second == 0 && t.TickOfSecond == 0 ? p2 : p1;
string s = t.Format(p);

// parsing
string s = // your input
var result = p1.Parse(s);
if (!result.Success)
    result = p2.Parse(s);
if (!result.Success)
    // throw some exception, etc.
LocalTime t = result.Value;
```

Comment: Note that code like this for parsing already exists but is internal right now: https://github.com/nodatime/nodatime/blob/master/src/NodaTime/Text/Patterns/CompositePattern.cs We may expose it at some point...